# what is the different in the upstream mode in checkout command?

Tags: git

what is the different in checkoutCommand in git with upsreamMode is

```
TRACK,
NOTRACK,
SET_UPSTREAM;
```

Does it have different meaning when you create or checkout branch ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch):

> When a local branch is started off a remote-tracking branch, Git sets up the branch (specifically the branch..remote and branch..merge configuration entries) so that git pull will appropriately merge from the remote-tracking branch.

Consider the following scenario where there exists a branch called `feature` on your Git repository, and you want to create a local branch from it:

```
git checkout origin/feature
git checkout -b feature
```

Now the local branch `feature` will track changes made to its counterpart in the repository.  This means when do a `git pull` your local branch can sync up with the remote.  But suppose you did *not* want your local `feature` branch to track anything.  The Git documentation states:

> That setting can be overridden by using the --track and --no-track options, and changed later using git branch --set-upstream-to.

In our example, you would achieve this via:

```
git checkout origin/feature
git checkout -b --no-track feature
```

Now when you `git pull` your local `feature` branch will not be updated.

But suppose you decide later on that you really do want your local `feature` branch to track its counterpart on the remote.  Then you could use the following:

```
git checkout feature
git --set-upstream origin/feature
```

Comment: Does the update upstream just update the config for the pull and merge command?

Comment: @user1365697 `--set- upstream` links the local branch with the remote counterpart for all operations (push, pull, fetch, etc.).